# Function to turn a GenTree to a Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, haskell

Given the following data structures, create a function which given a `GenTree`, turns it into a `BinTree`:

- Each in order `NodeG` matches a `NodeB` node in the Binary Tree;
- The left son of `NodeB` matches the first son of `NodeG`;
- The right son of `NodeB` is the next node which follows `NodeG` (this means, the next node in order between the childen of `NodeG` 's parents)

Visual example ( `GenTree` left, `BinTree` right)

```
    1                       1
/ |  |  \                  / \
2 3  4   5                2   E  
    /|\                  / \
   6 7 8                E   3
                           / \
                          E   4
                             / \
                            6   5
                           / \
                          E   7
                             / \
                            E   8
```

---

```
data GenTree a = EmptyG | NodeG a [GenTree a]
                                         deriving (Show)

data BinTree a = EmptyB | NodeB (BinTree a) a (BinTree a)
                                                     deriving (Show)
```

. I can't figure out how to make the helper function (aux) of the main function work.

```
g2b :: (GenTree a) -> (BinTree a)

g2b EmptyG = EmptyB
g2b (NodeG x ts) = NodeB (aux ts) x EmptyB

aux :: [GenTree a] -> (BinTree a)

aux [] = EmptyB
aux (NodeG x xs) : xss = NodeB (aux xs) x (aux xss) ((NodeG x xs) xss)
```

The last line of code is the one that doesn't work and the one I can't understand

Comment: Your problem is kind of underspecified in my opinion. `GenTree`s are bigger than `BinTree`s, in the sense that they have more stuff in them: a `NodeG` has many children whereas a `NodeB` has only two. What should your code do when you encounter a `NodeG` that doesn't fit into a `NodeB`? You'll need to come up with some sort of flattening strategy

Comment: Added more in depth explanation of the problem and a visual example of how the function should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what should it return if the node is an `EmptyG`, for example:

```
   1
 / | \
E  2  3
```

I did it like this `aux (EmptyG:xs)= EmptyB` but it doesn't make much sense. The problem in this case is what value to put in `a` so you don't lose the rest of the tree (`xs`).

Anyway this code works for the cases with no `EmptyG`:

```
aux :: [GenTree a] -> (BinTree a)
aux [] = EmptyB
aux (EmptyG:xs)= EmptyB  
aux ((NodeG x []):xs) = NodeB (EmptyB) x (aux xs)
aux ((NodeG x ys):xs) = NodeB (aux ys) x (aux xs)
```

From your example:

```
(NodeG 1 [NodeG 2 [], NodeG 3 [], NodeG 4 [NodeG 6 [], NodeG 7 [], NodeG 8 []], NodeG 5[]])
```

It produces:

```
NodeB (NodeB EmptyB 2 (NodeB EmptyB 3 (NodeB (NodeB EmptyB 6 (NodeB EmptyB 7 (NodeB EmptyB 8 EmptyB))) 4 (NodeB EmptyB 5 EmptyB)))) 1 EmptyB
```

Which, if I didn't mess up while doing it by hand, is the desired outcome.